# img tag data:image in Chrome

Tags: html, image, google-chrome

In my web application I'm using data:image to display images. In Internet Explorer 11 I can see the image but in Chrome I can't. Chrome displays an error in javascript console; "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL". I tried it also in incognito window to disable all extensions. I can see some other data:image samples in Chrome. But I can't see my image. I created a sample page to show you. The following page - http://oktay.tv/temp/img.html - shows image correctly in IE11. My Chrome version is 39.0.2171.71 in Windows OS.

Comment: Not showing in Firefox 34.0.5, either on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

It might be a long shot, but try to convert the image again. I test it with another image and just change your code and it worked. The only explanation i get is that your src might be invalid.

[Tested with Chrome 39 (64 bits) OSX ]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I forgot to add quotation mark after src attirbute. It seems IE automatically adds quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example you post. isn't the src quotation closed?

```
     <html>
      <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA( ... )Hq/lyAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC/">
</html>
```

Comment: IE adds quotations itself. I didn't put quotation marks.

Comment: @OktayO, the example in chrome there has quotation marks also.

Comment: @sendreams At that time Chrome didn't add quotation marks but IE added automatically. I corrected the source with quotation marks.